# Python: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error

I am trying to read through lines of a text file to split and pull strings that are between # signs. When I run my code I am getting the error

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here is my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#function
def parameterPull(line):
    if line.count('#') > 0:
        temp = eachLine.split('#',1)[1]
        temp2 = temp.split('#',1)[0]
        temp3 = temp.split('#',1)[1]

        #write these scripts to a file
        parameterFile.write('\n'+temp2+'\n')

        #check for multiple instance on the same line
        if temp3.count('#') > 0:
            parameterPull(temp3)

#make replacements
for eachLine in resultFile:
    parameterPull(eachLine)


parameterFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `line` instead of `eachLine` in the function body. I made a quick test with a sample `resultFile` (several lines of `# x # y # z #`) and no error occurred after making the change.